# Why AWS Athena returns "string" datatype to all table's fields on "show create table" command or describe tables

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

Why AWS Athena returns "string" datatype to all table's fields on 
"show create table" command or on describe tables:
for example table `t_mus_albums`:

```
albumid (bigint)
title (string)
artistid (bigint)
```

whan running 
`show create table t_mus_albums`;
I get:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `t_mus_albums`(
  `albumid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `title` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `artistid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
```

Comment: Is your table a CSV table?

Comment: Yes this is a csv file

Comment: For CSV this is expected behavior per documentation. More explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be doing something wrong or while generating the table automatically, you may not have correct formatted data.

Here are the systematic steps to solve your problem.
Assume that your data is in below format.

```
ID,Code,City,State
41,5,"Youngstown", OH
42,52,"Yankton", SD
46,35,"Yakima", WA
42,16,"Worcester", MA
43,37,"Wisconsin Dells", WI
36,5,"Winston-Salem", NC
```

Then your create table will go something like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example.tbl_datatype (
  `id` int,
  `code` int,
  `city` string,
  `state` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://example-bucket/location/a/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Then, run the Query to description the table.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_datatype;
```

It will give you output something like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tbl_datatype`(
  `id` int, 
  `code` int, 
  `city` string, 
  `state` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://example-bucket/location/a/';
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use CSV serde and not e.g. TEXT serde.
CSV serde does support only `string` data type, so all columns are of this type.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html

> The OpenCSV SerDe [...] Converts all column type values to STRING.

The documentation outlines some conditions under which the table schema could be different than all `string`s ("*For example, it parses the values into BOOLEAN, BIGINT, INT, and DOUBLE data types when it can discern them*"), but apparently this was not effective in your case.